# Executing a powershell script remotely

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a powershell script stored on a server and need certain users to be able to send a command to run this script from their workstations. I have went onto the server and run the command to allow remote powershell. Below is the script I am running along with a screen shot of my error.

```
invoke-command { powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass C:\script directory } -computername  -credential (domain).local\Administrator
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: What is wrong with the format?

Comment: It would be helpful to copy/paste the error message.  Some corporate networks block imgur.com, so some of us can't see your error.

Comment: You attempt to remote into a machine to enable remoting?

Comment: [server] Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message
: WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occured while using Ker
beros authentication: There are currently no logon servers available to service
 the logon request.
 Possible causes are:
  -The user name or password specified are invalid.
  -Kerberos is used when no authentication method and no user name are specifie
d.

 

.

Comment: -Change the authentication method; add the destination computer to the WinRM
TrustedHosts configuration setting or use HTTPS transport.
 Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated.
   -For more information about WinRM configuration, run the following command:
winrm help config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting H
elp topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I can remote in and run the script if that what you are asking, but I can't have individual users do this.

Comment: Do the users have permission to log onto the server?  Have you put them in the server's Users group?

Comment: @TonyHinkle The users do have permissions, when I get the error I am using Admin credentials

Answer (score 0):

you must perform some tuning to run remote powershell. may be some of these rules doesn't apply.

1. enable ps-remoting

`powershell -noprofile -command Enable-PsRemoting -Force`

2. enable wimRm service (Windows remote administration)

`sc config "WinRM" start= delayed-auto`

`sc start "WinRM"`

3. add firewall rules for winRm service

`netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)" profile=domain new enable=yes`

`netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name="Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)" profile=private,public new enable=yes profile=private,public`

4. lookup WS-Management TrustedHost content

`winrm g winrm/config/client`

you will get something like

```
    Client
      NetworkDelayms = 5000
      URLPrefix = wsman
      AllowUnencrypted = false
    Auth
      Basic = true
      Digest = true
      Kerberos = true
      Negotiate = true
      Certificate = true
      CredSSP = false
    DefaultPorts
      HTTP = 5985
      HTTPS = 5986
    TrustedHosts = MyComputer
```

5. update list of trusted hosts to fit the workstations allowed to connect

`winrm s winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="server,computer01,computer02,etc"}`

you can check if it works with

`winrm quickconfig`

I think that's all. hope it helps

Comment: I am getting this error when attempting to add workstations
PS C:\Users\Administrator> winrm s winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="DM30167"}
Error: Invalid use of command line. Type "winrm -?" for help.

Comment: @user326334 I've posted a new answer because I have difficulties with comments formatting. hope it helps

Comment: Ok I went through and did all of that, tried to remotely run the script from a machine added to the trusted hosts and still get the same error. Below is the script I am using. invoke-command { powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass C:\Applicat\OCI Software\permScript.ps1 } -computername server -credential domain.local\Administrator Read-Host -Prompt "exit"

Answer (score 0):

@user326334

I post another answer because I need to clarify myself. perhaps I completely misunderstood you, and I need to view exact description of error.

but some comments...

Invoke-command may run powershell commands directly.

the script you're calling contains spaces in path, consider quoting.

I may miss something but I think you are mixing *Invoke-Command parameters* with *powershell cmdLets* as **-credential...** with **read-host -Prompt...**

try this and let me know what's happening

```
$s = New-PSSession -computer "server" -credential "domain.local\Administrator"

Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { ... }
```

for instance, this work perfectly for me

```
$s = New-PSSession -computer "LENOVO" -credential "lenovo\administrador"
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal‌​.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator) }
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { cmd /c "sc query remoteregistry"; $lastexitcode } 
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { Get-WSManInstance -ResourceURI winrm/config/client | select -ExpandProperty TrustedHosts}
```

if still in trouble, may be the authentication mode you're using.

please visit [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/51687383-c430-449f-91f3-6cebfe1c7dfa/invokecommand-as-remote-local-user?forum=winserverpowershell) and [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/48aebf89-2ffd-45c4-8285-45cbb58d3fa1/invoke-command-bypassing-credentials?forum=winserverpowershell) for further information